# How do I get myself out of docker hijacked network situation on my Debian VM?

Tags: networking, debian, docker, grub

I ran into a problem with `wg-easy` docker in trying to set up Wireguard using docker on my Debian VM so I changed `network_mode` to `host` as a last resort without learning about the consequences... The container having `NET_ADMIN` capability then hijacked my Debian host and made it unusable. Is there a way to get myself out of the situation without having to reinstall Debian?

Docker is obviously auto-start. I've tried GRUB command line but don't know what to type there so I can enter `sh` or something where I can disable docker auto-start.

I tried `single` mode (with `systemd.unit=rescue` but it does not appear to do anything in my case) and it actually is already in the GRUB graphical menu in advanced options. The screen of the noVNC freezes here.

[Screenshot of noVNC terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yorpc.jpg)

UPDATE

At this point I'm convinced that the docker container having `NET_ADMIN` and running as root (or at least docker was running as root) had permanently changed something on the network layer. How do I untangle that? I could just reinstall Debian from scratch, it's just a VM and I don't have valuable data saved on it. But what's the fun in that?

I managed to use the installation ISO image to boot and disabled docker service, modified `docker-compose.yml` removing the `network_mode` line so it falls back to the default behaviour. I've also deleted existing containers. But the system boot is still stuck at the screenshot point. The last few lines has to do with TCP, binding hash table entries, NET, etc. Is there a way to "reset" network side of things on an existing Debian installation? I hate to mention Windows but Windows seems to have a reset option for resetting network config...

Comment: google "linux grub single user mode". It's been described ad nauseam.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider for the idea but by "hijacked" I mean it does not have a command line, nor is its ports open any more. So the situation is that on the network interface level, all that is there is what's in the docker image (or the container, which is an instance of the docker image). So really I need something outside of Linux but can work on the Linux installation from the outside to perform a surgery to remove the tumor. I don't really know what's inside a `wg-easy` docker image but it's just a blank screen with the text cursor blinking, I can't interact with it.

Comment: The only reason why I can still see the GRUB boot screen is because of QEMU's noVNC terminal. I can launch the noVNC view from the browser UI of the host of the VM, which is a Synology NAS server. I cannot SSH onto the server anymore.

Comment: The reason why I have not installed Wireguard directly on the container manager of the Synology NAS is because its Linux kernel version is too old... To make it work, it involves a level of hacking and kernel patching which I am not comfortable or confident enough with. The NAS server works well otherwise. I don't want to break it hence the Debian VM way. It turned out to be the best, because otherwise I might break the NAS server itself...