# What to check on what is blocking my open port on Debian?

Tags: networking, debian, docker

I would have posted my attempts but I currently do not have access to this Debian VM... (see related question [How do I get myself out of docker hijacked network situation on my Debian VM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1156967/how-do-i-get-myself-out-of-docker-hijacked-network-situation-on-my-debian-vm.))

Anyway, the problem I was facing was that the container which has `NET_ADMIN` capability and port forwarding definition in docker just isn't accessible to the outside world on my local LAN. I tried using `curl` to visit the URL for its web admin page, it works with `localhost` and docker's virtual network, but it is just not accessible to other machines on my LAN. The listening is already on `0.0.0.0` as well as on `::1` and I have used `iptables -L` to see the port open to anywhere. What/where else to check?

The weirdest part is that this is not the first or the only docker I have set up on this Debian VM. I use Portainer for management and the web UI runs in a container itself. It has port 9443 exposed and I could access the web UI URL via the Debian VM's LAN IP address. It's just this `wg-easy` container's port `51821` isn't reachable over the LAN IP address.